# omnisharp with emacs's company mode does not show parameters and return values

Tags: c#, emacs, omnisharp

I use omnisharp-emacs, but company mode does not show parameters and return values like it's doc.
In it's github like this:

[image: Screenshot from GitHub]

but in my emacs like this, only show method name:
[image: What I'm seeing]